# Is there any way of stopping Sublime Text's Git plugin messing with the status bar?

Tags: git, plugins, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using the Sublime Text [Git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git) plugin (with ST3), but I don't need or want the stuff it adds to the status bar (at the bottom of the UI). I can't seem to turn that off though. In Git.sublime-settings I've set both `statusbar_branch` and `statusbar_status` to false, which has removed some but not all of the plugin's status bar output. I still get "Comparing against: HEAD". Is there any way to disable this too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The “Comparing against HEAD” message in the status bar is actually not produced by the Git plugin, but by GitGutter.

```
  // Determines whether GitGutter will show informations in the status bar
  // Set "none" to hide these informations
  // Set "default" to show in the status bar what you are comparing
  // against, how many lines have been inserted or modified and how many regions
  // have been deleted.
  // Set "all" to also show on what branch you are
  "show_status": "default",
```

The default configuration is to show information from GitGutter in the status bar.

If you wish to disable it, simply set `show_status` to `none`, as indicated by the comments.